# How to display product attribute set in product list page via custom module in magento 2.3.3?

Tags: product-attribute, product-page, attribute-set, product-listing, catalog-product

I am trying show product **Attribute set** in product listing page.I want to achieve via custom module.

can someone help to achieve this solution?

Thanks in advance.